# Zsh always asks if I mean git blog instead of git log

Tags: zsh

I work on a lot of websites and often there is a blog directory. Issue is whenever there is i get this

```
➜  project-name git:(master) ✗ git log
zsh: correct 'log' to 'blog' [nyae]?
```

Can I just force it to *never* *ever* suggest git blog?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this on my system.  If it's not already there, try enabling the expanded zsh completion system by adding this line to `~/.zshrc`: `autoload -U compinit && compinit`.  With that, expansions will be git-aware and based on `git` commands instead of files (e.g. `git bl<tab>` will expand to `git blame`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like this worked from the comment from @gairfowl

```
autoload -U compinit && compinit
```

I'm using oh-my-zsh so I'm surprised this didnt work out of the box.

Answer (score 2):

Add `unsetopt correct_all` to your zsh dotfiles (e.g., `~/.zshrc`). This will disable this behavior for all corrections.

Comment: For just git, you could use `alias git='nocorrect git'`